# Next Js 13.3.0 rewrites doesn't work for external API

Tags: cors, external, nextjs-rewrites

I'm trying to call an external API using rewrites from Next server to avoid CORS error. To do that I've been reading Next docs [Rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) but is not working for me.

My next.config.js file is like this:

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  async rewrites() {
   // let externalServer = process.env.EXTERNAL_API_URL
    return [      
        {
          source: "/api/:path*",
          destination: "https://localhost:50575/api/:path*",
        },             
    ]
  },
}
```

I have tried to use that [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-http-proxy-middleware), but if you see that page recomend use rewrites because works like a proxy, if I'm not misunderstanding.

The rewrites seems not working it just fetching data from Next server instead external API,I don't have any error at all.

Comment: Can nextjs server connect to https://localhost:50575?